# Issue on binding same property to multiple controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF window that looks as follows:

[image]
These controls are binded like this (shown only few):

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Code"/>
<ComboBox  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="DdlLstCardCodes" FontWeight="Bold" SelectedItem="{Binding TransactionDetails.TransactionCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,IsAsync=True}" ItemsSource ="{Binding ListCurrencyCardCodes}"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Currency"/>
<ComboBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="1" Name="DdlCurrency" SelectedIndex="0" FontWeight="Bold" SelectedItem="{Binding TransactionDetails.CurrencyCode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,IsAsync=True}" ItemsSource="{Binding UsDollerTransfer.LstCountryCode}"/>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Amount"/>
<TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding TransactionDetails.TransactionAmount, Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat=0{0.0}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="TextBoxAmount"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Charges"/>
<TextBox Grid.Column="7" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding TransactionDetails.Charges, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,StringFormat=N3}" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="TextBoxcharges"/>

<Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="9" Background="#0199ED"  Foreground="#D9ffff" Content="+" Name="BtnAddMore" Click="BtnAddMore_OnClick" />

<ToggleButton Name="BtnProceed" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="11" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#0199ED"  Foreground="#D9ffff" Content="Proceed" Command="{Binding Path=ProceedCommand,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<ToggleButton Name="PrntButton" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="11" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="#0199ED"  Foreground="#D9ffff" Content="Print Reciept" IsThreeState="True"/>
```

On clicking + button I am again generating all these controls with same binding from code behind like this

```
private void BtnAddMore_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
       _btnCount++;
       var txBlockCode = new TextBlock {Text = "Code", VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center};
       var ddlCardCodes = new ComboBox
       {
           FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
           BorderBrush = Brushes.Black,
           Name = "NewDdlCard" + _btnCount
       };
       ddlCardCodes.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("ListCurrencyCardCodes"));
       ddlCardCodes.SetBinding(Selector.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding("TransactionDetails.TransactionCode"));
       // same like other controls
 }
```

On Changing Some of these Parameters like(Currency, Amount, Charges, MSBFEE, Rate) the Total got changed with calculation like this

```
private void TransactionDetails_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "CurrencyCode":
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(TransactionDetails.CurrencyCode)) { return; }
        var getRate= (from x in context.DbCurrencies.Where(x => x.CurrencyCode == TransactionDetails.CurrencyCode) select x).FirstOrDefault();
        TransactionDetails.CurrencyRate=1/(getRate.Rate);
        TransactionDetails.Charges=9.85;
        TransactionDetails.SubTotal = TransactionDetails.CurrencyRate * TransactionDetails.TransactionAmount;
        TransactionDetails.Total =
            Convert.ToDouble(Math.Round((((100 - TransactionDetails.Charges) / 100) * TransactionDetails.SubTotal) + Convert.ToDouble(TransactionDetails.MsbFee), 2));
        //Also some other conditions and other cases
    }
}
```

`TransactionDetails` is my Entity with Properties (`TransactionCode`, `CurrencyCode`, `TransactionAmount`, `CurrencyRate`, `Charges`, `SubTotal` and `Total`)

**My Issues :**

1. As dynamically generated controls is bind to same property, on changing one item, other
   items who are binded to same property got changed to latest changed
   value(See I fillup the form like the provided Image and clicked + means I will get same panel to be inserted again in the new panel if i am selecting currency `AUD` then the previous changed to `AUD` from `INR` as they bind to same property `TransactionDetails.CurrencyCode`) same apply to every controls.
2. While clicking Proceed button I want all these data(means multiple
   rows) to be saved in database. But as it has binded with same
   property only 1st controls with that property got inserted into
   database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your Program design maybe based on your misunderstanding of the mvvm patern

to do what you want you need todo the following things

**Create a View which contains a ItemsControl**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding RecieptListe, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="#0199ED"  
                Foreground="#D9ffff" Content="+" Name="BtnAddMore" 
                Command="{Binding AddRecieptCommand,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <ToggleButton Name="BtnProceed" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  
                  Background="#0199ED"  Foreground="#D9ffff" Content="Proceed" 
                  Command="{Binding Path=ProceedCommand,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<ToggleButton Name="PrntButton" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Background="#0199ED"  
              Foreground="#D9ffff" Content="Print Reciept" IsThreeState="True"/>
```

**create a ViewModel which has a ObservableCollection of RecieptVM**

```
public class RecieptListeVM
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> RecieptListe { get; set; }

    public ICommand AddRecieptCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand ProceedCommand { get; set; }

    public ICommand PrintCommand { get; set; }
}
```

this class will contain your logic to add an element to your list print and start calculate

now you can use your current Usercontrole as Datatemplate in your ItemsControl

the result looks like

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply due to weekend. Suppose I have a Method `AddControls()` in my viewmodel. So how do I bind this to the  ObservableCollection to add these controls?

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra  in your `AddControls()` you only need todo `MyObcoll.Add( new MyDetailVM())` the View will show the Usercontrol for this VM via Datatemplate. Which means you will never ever have and need a UIElement in your Viewmodel :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're binding to the same instance of an object. If you want to keep track of different instances of properties, you need to assign another instance of an object to the DataContext of each set of controls. So whenever you call the BtnAddMore_OnClick event, you need to create another instance of your data, in addition to creating the extra panel.

I also recommend you look into MVVM. As this makes working with WPF a lot easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same binding source to store different values. Each source stores exactly one instance of whatever type (One currency unit, one amount, etc.).

To get along you should create a new instance of your storage and bind this one to the new controls. This should fix your first issue.

When clicking Proceed iterate over all the instances created before and write them to database. This should adress your second issue.